# Cancel previous request in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable with json data and when user click on generate PDF it will start the PDF generation process(notice no ajax call to server). Let's say that data is large enough that it takes 2 to 5 minutes to generate PDF depending on size of data. In a meanwhile if the same user sends another request to filter that data based on search criteria is there a way to cancel previous request.

P.S: I am using **jsdpdf** to generate PDF and **alasql** to generate Excel

```
document.getElementById('btnPDF').addEventListener('click', function () {
     // Can we cancel previous request anywhere inside this block?
    $('.loader-modal').show(function () {
        DownloadPDF();
    });
});
function DownloadPDF() {
    // Very simple function just for demo purpose
    var columns = ["ID", "Name", "Description"];
    var rows = [
        [1, "Shaw", "HI"],
        [2, "Nelson", "I can be very long" ],
        [3, "Garcia", "Same here"]        
];

    // Only pt supported (not mm or in)
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
    doc.save('table.pdf');
}
```

**Problem statement Simplified:**

On click of Button A a function gets called which will write to console some data lets say 1000 times (just to introduce time factor). While its writing data If user click same button again is there a way to cancel previous request? 
For design purpose we want the user to be able to click that button again at any time (even before the previous request didn't got completed) and avoiding page refresh.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I already mentioned ajax call is not in picture.

Comment: If and how that is gonna be done we need to know what `DownloadPDF()` does. Is it calling a server, is it process local data only, is it doing a hyper link navigation or a form post,...

Comment: @LGSon I updated my question to simplify it further. And to answer your question as I said I already have json data with me, so all I do is pass it to the third party JS library which I don't have any control of it.

Comment: If that library has an "abort/cancel" method you can cancel it, if not, then you need to reload the page, which would/should cancel all local processes.

Comment: @LGSon You got it but can this be achieved without reloading? This should have been my original question :)

Comment: No, unless you run that code in an iframe, which you might can, and that would avoid the need to reload the main page.

Comment: how about a web worker?

Comment: @bambam Since that barely hit the market, and being experimental, I would advice against using it in production.

Comment: @bambam Of course, for each and everyone to decide, I do think you should have mentioned that in your answer though, it being experimental and to expect a behavior change, as if one invest time into something one would most like want to know before going down that road

Comment: I agree, added the explicit word experimental in the answer instead of only writing compatibilty needs to be checked and warned about possible API changes. @LGSon

Comment: Great...+1 from me, as it is very good we get new stuff to deal with issues like this